# Why is DataStage writing NULL string values as empty strings, while other data types correctly have NULL values

Tags: hive, hdfs, datastage

I have a DataStage parallel job that writes to Hive as the final stage in a long job. I can view the data that is about to be written and there are many `NULL` strings that I want to see in the Hive table.

However, when I view the table that is created, there are no NULL strings, they all get converted into empty strings `''` instead. I can see other datatypes, like `DECIMAL(5,0)` have NULL values and I can select these, e.g.

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE decimal_column IS NULL;`

The process for writing to Hive is to store the data in a staging table in a delimited text format. This is then pushed through a generic CDC process and results in data being written to a new partition in an ORC format table.

The only option I can see for handling NULL values is "Null Value" in the HDFS File Connector Stage. If I leave this blank then I get empty strings and if I type in 'NULL' then 'NULL' is what I get, i.e. not a `NULL`, but the string 'NULL'.

I can't change the process as it's in place for literally thousands of jobs already. Is there any way to get my string values to be `NULL` or am I stuck with empty strings?

Answer (score 0):

According to the IBM documentation, an empty String in double-quotation <kbd>""</kbd> should help.

> **Null value**
>
> Specify the character or string that represents null values in the data. For a source stage, input data that has the value
> that you specify is set to null on the output link. For a target
> stage, in the output file that is written to the file system, null
> values are represented by the value that is specified for this
> property. **To specify that an empty string represents a null value,
> specify "" (two double quotation marks).**

Source: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=reference-properties-file-connector

Comment: I tested this and it doesn't appear to do anything. I think the default behaviour is to store a NULL string as an empty string, i.e. "" and all this does is to confirm that behaviour. I want a NULL string to be stored as a NULL value, like it already does for dates, decimals, etc.

Comment: Did you try putting something like `If Len(Trim(mylink.mystring1)) = 0 Then SetNull() Else mylink.mystring1`  in a transformer before the output stage, so the stage gets not a Null String but a NUll value?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. If I write the final output to a Data Set then I see NULLs for strings. It's only when I write it to HDFS that it changes NULLs to empty strings. I can "fix" it with an HQL script, but I wondered why the default behaviour was to do this and if it was possible to change it

Comment: Hmm... then I suggest to open a support case at IBM. Sorry I couldn't help.